# php mkdir creates a folder with lock icon

Tags: php, ubuntu

I tried to make a new directory with `mkdir()`, but the folder I made has a little lock icon on top of it. I tried to delete it manually, it doesn't allow me, saving I have no permission to delete it.

What may I do now? My operating system is Ubuntu

My PHP code is:

```
mkdir("foldername", 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `chmod("foldername",0777);` after `mkdir`.
But you shouldn't use 0777, it gives persmission to this directory to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access you should be able to delete this folder. Your php program is probably running as a different user than the user you are logged into the command prompt as. Running the command as a super user should override that though.

Be careful. The below command will delete the folder and everything inside the folder.

sudo rm -r -f /path/

Answer (score 0):

`sudo chmod 777 -R </filepath>`

Make sure you **put your file path** and this will allow you to **Read (7) Write (7) and Execute (7)** all the folders/files in that path

Comment: It may compromise security of the folders. Do more research!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the lock from the icon of the folder type this commant -:

```html
sudo chmod 777 [path of folder] -R
```